# Erroneous review task count in topbar, potential bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The little orange counter in the top bar with the number of outstanding review tasks has been off for the last couple of days.
At least in my profile the actual number of tasks does not appear to correspond to the number of posts in any of the individual different review queues, nor does it match the total number of posts.

Am I overlooking a queue or something or is there a small bug somewhere?

[image: Server Fault - Outstanding review tasks]

Comment: It's a stupid, broken mess (like everything related to the crappy review system). I added an Adblock Element Hiding rule to get rid of it after a day or two as this annoyed the crap out of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design, [amongst other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match) it is most likely to be caching in action. See the linked question on mSE for some more details.

Comment: Duh! Didn't think of searching http://meta.stackexchange.com/, which in retrospect would have been the obvious place. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The count in the top bar is site-wide, and includes [items which you may have already reviewed or skipped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233535/189912), both of which no longer appear for you in the individual queue counts.

There's also caching, but that only lasts a minute or so.

To see the full counts, visit [/review](https://serverfault.com/review) while logged out (e.g. in an incognito window).